ASP.NET Core 8 page routing not working with optional parameter
I have defined this route
@page "/{countryCode}/{regionCode}/{cityName}/listing/{title?}/{address}/{uniqueId:Guid}"

which technically should work for
/gb/eng/luton/listing/76-dunstable-road/d1b86843-f76d-4e81-a5b5-413e37ce0d1d

and
/gb/eng/luton/listing/some-title/76-dunstable-road/d1b86843-f76d-4e81-a5b5-413e37ce0d1d

But this does not work for the first case, am I missing something?
EDIT:
parameter setup
public async Task OnGetAsync(string countryCode, string regionCode, string cityName, string? title, string address, Guid uniqueId)
{...}


Seems like you are using Blazor component. You can define two paths with one of it without the {title?}. @page "/{countryCode}/{regionCode}/{cityName}/listing/{address}/{uniqueId:Guid}" and @page "/{countryCode}/{regionCode}/{cityName}/listing/{title}/{address}/{uniqueId:Guid}"

Besides, can you show how you define the parameters, especially the title?

maybe the optional parameter is not able to be placed except the last parameter of the endpoint, otherwise we will get 404 error like what you get from the first case. And I'm afraid that using multiple route templates like what YongShun shared in the comment is the best workaround...

Or @page "/{countryCode}/{regionCode}/{cityName}/listing/{address}/{uniqueId:Guid}/{title?}"

@YongShun I am using asp.net core web app 8.0, not blazor, you can only have one page directive in a .cshtml file so having multiple wont work
TinyWang this app is done to support existing url structure, so unfortunately the  url structure cannot be changed.
I also shown the OnGet of my .cshtml.cs file

Thanks a lot for your kind reply  and support existing url structure, so unfortunately the url structure cannot be changed --> I'm afraid we have to change the url now because the url we currently use is proved to be not able to match your requirement.
